# Why does one of my finaries fail with version `GLIBC_2.27' not found

Tags: c, cmake, ld, glibc, ldd

I am cross-compiling by binaries identically by `CMake` clauses like

```
add_executable(mybinary1 mybinary1.c util_temp.c)
target_link_libraries(mybinary1 m)

add_executable(mybinary2 mybinary2.c util_temp.c)
target_link_libraries(mybinary2 m)
```

Unfortunately, one of them fails when running on target platform:

```
/mybinary2: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ./mybinary2)
```

First binary runs well.

`ldd` shows

```
# ldd mybinary2
./mybinary2: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ./mybinary2)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ed1d000)
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76fa2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76f27000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76de6000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76fcc000)
# ldd mybinary1
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ee09000)
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76ece000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76e53000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76d12000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76efb000)
```

What does it mean and how to solve it? Can I compile against specific version of a library? Why does it refer `GLIBS` indirectly, via `libm`?

If I do

```
target_link_libraries(mybinary2 m -static)
```

it starts to work but binary becomes x20 larger.

I also tried

```
__asm__(".symver realpath,realpath@GLIBC_2.19");
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

in `mybinary2.c` with no effect.

```
target_link_libraries(mybinary2 m -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)
```

in `CMakeLists.txt` with no effect.

```
target_link_libraries(mybinary2 m libc.so.6:2.19)
```

with error message

```
[build] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -llibc.so.6:2.19
```

Is latter syntax correct? How to see, which version (and of what) is on my system?

I tried commands like

```
ld -llibc
```

but neither work.

On my target computer (it is Raspberry Pi with old version of OS):

```
# ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18+deb8u10) 2.19
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

I don't know how to use cross `ldd` on source computer.

Comment: What's the output from `ldd -r ...`?  That should hopefully show what symbol(s) are causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what your target computer outputs via `ldd --version` and based on the error (which also explains why a static link works):

You have a GLIBC version mismatch, i.e. you compile it using `GLIBC 2.27` but on the target computer you have `GLIBC 2.19`. You either need to crosscompile with a lower version than you are currently using or upgrade `glibc` on the target computer.

EDIT:  To clarify which errors and general info I mean:

1)

```
# ldd mybinary2
./mybinary2: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ./mybinary2)
```

2. 

```
# ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18+deb8u10) 2.19
```

EDIT2: Did a quick search and assuming you are crosscompiling on debian you could use the following command to get available package versions:

```
apt-cache policy myPackage
```

Where `myPackage` will most likely be `libc6-dev-armhf-cross` for your current needs.

EDIT3: As Andrew Henle pointed out. The easiest solution is to directly compile your project on the target device (or a compilation environment that is identical to the one on the target). Consider the above only if the target device is limiting you in doing so.

Comment: *You either need to crosscompile with a lower version than you are currently using or upgrade glibc on the target computer.*  If the source code is compatible with `GLIBC 2.19`, the easiest solution is to just compile on a `GLIBC 2.19` system.

Comment: That is the first option that I pointed out here. Unless of course you mean not cross-compiling at all. Which may not always be favorable due to limited processing power on the target device (for example). Am I missing your point? Edit: asking because english is not my first language.

Comment: *Unless of course you mean not cross-compiling at all.*  That's exactly what I mean.  Worst case, use something like VirtualBox to run a VM on the later system and install an older OS release on the VM that's compatible with the older system.  Even that's a lot easier then cross compiling or trying to update `libc`.

Comment: Ah I understand you now. Yes that is indeed the easiest solution. I assumed that OP has to get around long compile times on an old RPi device. I will add it as a 3rd edit.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the target device - it just has to be an compilation environment that's compatible with the target device.

Comment: Fixed, I think I know what you mean as I've done something similar to this some time ago using an emulator (i.e. qemu for the given architecture) and a copy of the environment (and `chroot`-ing into it). But then again the only reason why I did it was that I was too lazy to handle the cross-compiling errors.

Comment: Ok suppose I found which package version I have. What next? Do you mean I need to uninstall it and install other version? Isn't it possible to specify version during config?

Comment: Regarding suggestion to compile on traget system -- is it really easier to run some old RaspberryPi image?

Comment: @Dims I'll start with question one: if I'm not mistaken you can have both packages installed **unless** it relies on dependencies that might collide with the previous one. However the best thing to do this is to use docker and create a contained (clean) environment for the build. As of question number two. It is somewhat easier, you can just copy the entire **root filesystem** and then using an emulator (QEMU) you can `chroot` into this environment and just build in it. Provided that you have the needed `-dev` packages and the compiler to do so. It's essentially the same as running a `VM`.

Comment: **Ad2)** Here is a link on [how to chroot into a filesystem with a different architecture](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41889/how-can-i-chroot-into-a-filesystem-with-a-different-architechture). **Ad1)** If you can have both packages installed then you can use either `update-alternatives` (on Debian) or you can specify to `CMake` the default compiler for your project (preferably within the toolchain file, but you can also set some variables like `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` etc.)